# Ubuntu's ls can show unicode characters, but tree cannot, even with tree --charset unicode

Tags: ubuntu, bash, unicode, ls, tree

Ubuntu 10.04's `ls` can show unicode characters, but `tree` cannot, even with `tree --charset unicode` or `utf8`.  Is there a way to solve it.  `echo` could interpret the escape characters except `cat list.txt | echo -e` won't work (`list.txt` comes from   `tree > list.txt`)

**Update: `tree -H www.somewhere.com` can output unicode (should be in UTF-8) but right now it seems this is the only way -- as a webpage.**

```
$ ls -R
.:
list2.txt  list.txt  久未在遊行場合露面的前總統李登輝.txt  遊行

./遊行:
大家2.txt  大家.txt

$ tree --charset unicode
.
|-- list2.txt
|-- list.txt
|-- \344\271\205\346\234\252\345\234\250\351\201\212\350\241\214\345\240\264\345\220\210\351\234\262\351\235\242\347\232\204\345\211\215\347\270\275\347\265\261\346\235\216\347\231\273\350\274\235.txt
`-- \351\201\212\350\241\214
    |-- \345\244\247\345\256\2662.txt
    `-- \345\244\247\345\256\266.txt

1 directory, 5 files

$ tree --charset utf8
.
├── list2.txt
├── list.txt
├── \344\271\205\346\234\252\345\234\250\351\201\212\350\241\214\345\240\264\345\220\210\351\234\262\351\235\242\347\232\204\345\211\215\347\270\275\347\265\261\346\235\216\347\231\273\350\274\235.txt
└── \351\201\212\350\241\214
    ├── \345\244\247\345\256\2662.txt
    └── \345\244\247\345\256\266.txt

1 directory, 5 files
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try this:

```
tree -N
```

Comment: it works!  great solution!

Comment: Works for me on Fedora 25.